# How to add text above and below each section in word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to be able to add tags to templates automatically use with phpword.
Phpword allows you to create blocks by using ${tagname} ... ${/tagname} around a block of text(https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html#cloneblock).

I want to create a macro to automatically add a tag to each section based of the contents page.
So far have tried GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading) which gets all the headings. From there I want to go to the line before the heading in the body of text and add a tag.
However I'm having but trying to move the selection here. Using selection.find will find the text within the contents page.

Here's my WIP code:

```
Sub AddTags()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim I, J As Integer
Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Content
Dim astrHeadings As Variant

' GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading) returns an array with references to all headings in the document
astrHeadings = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)
   
For I = LBound(astrHeadings) To UBound(astrHeadings)
    
    'split on spaces
    Dim Words() As String
    Words = Split(Trim(astrHeadings(I)))
    intials = ""
    
    For J = 1 To UBound(Words)
       intials = intials & Left(Words(J), 1)
    Next
    
    
    'index of first word
    Start = InStr(1, astrHeadings(I), Words(1), vbTextCompare)
    
    
    Found = Selection.Find.Execute(FindText:=Trim(Right(astrHeadings(I), Len(astrHeadings(I)) - Start)))
    
    Rng = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=Selection.Start, End:=ActiveDocument.Range.End)
    
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToPrevious, Count:=1
    
    Debug.Print intials
    Selection.TypeText ("${" & intials & "}")
Next        
End Sub
```

Comment: The term 'Section' has a very specific meaning in Word.  Your reference to Headings suggests that you are not using the tern 'Section' in the same way that Word does.  Could you please review your use of the word section and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: @freeflow thanks for your comment, what would the correct terminology be? I mean the header and the body below the header up until the next header/subheader

Comment: Any terminology that does not carelessly confuse the issue.  Your clarification thus far shows that you are not interested in Word Sections at all, just headings and the text until the next heading.  If the headings have been done correctly, you can process the storyrange(wdmaintextstory) by looking for a paragraph that is not outline level 10 (i.e. a heading) and then searching the subsequent paragraphs until you again find a paragraph that is not outline level 10.